# 2 attribute in 2-dimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to create a 2 dimensional array, which the second array has 2 attributes. Is it possible in php? Becuase I know it's possible in Pascal

example

```
| Doc |        Term        |
|  0  |   0 => 'Term1'     |
|     |    1 =>  5         |
----------------------------
|  1  |   0 => 'Term'2'    |
|     |    1 => 2          |
```

My question is, How to create this 2-dimensional array and how to access each value? 
Thank you

Comment: Do you know how to create an array? Do you know how to access a value in an array? A nested array is not a special case here.

Comment: Yes I know how to create array and access value in an array.. So is it not possible to array above in php? Should I create 3-dimensional array or any other way? thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is simple array nesting:

```
$a = array(array('Term1', 5), array('Term2', 2));
$a[1][1] === 2;
```

This is an extremely basic question. Consider consulting a php book or tutorial.

Comment: I just think about using 3-dimensional array. Sorry, but thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just make the value of the item in the array, another array, you can do this as deep as you like. e.g.,

### Creating the array

```
$doc = array(
    array(
        'Term1',
        5
    ),
    array(
        'Term 2',
        2
    )
)
```

Since no ID is set, the id's are automatically generated, starting at 0. You can set the ID if you want like this:

```
$doc = array(
    0 => array(
        3 => 'Term1',
        9 => 5
    ),
    1 => array(
        3 => 'Term 2',
        10 => 2
    )
)
```

### Retrieving data from the array

```
$term1 = $doc[0][0];
echo $term1; // outputs 'Term 1'
```

Comment: At some point you should either upvote or accept an answer by clicking on the tick so others can find your accepted solution when they view the question